# How to zoom in on the last marker set down?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I got everything working but can't seem to find the right code to get the app zoomed in on the last marker placed down.

This is my code:

```
getEarthquakes(){       
    return fetch('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData =>{
       var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < responseData.features.length; i++) {
          var coords = responseData.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          var marker = {
            key: responseData.features[i].id,
            coordinate: {
              latitude: coords[1],
              longitude: coords[0],
            }
          }
          markers.push(marker);
        }

        this.setState({
         markers: markers,
         loaded: true,
         marker: markers,
         latitude: coords[1],
         longitude: coords[0]
        });
      }
    ).done();
}


render() {
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView.Animated
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.state.marker}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          followUserLocation={true}>

             {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                <MapView.Marker
                  key={marker.key}
                  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                />
             ))}
        </MapView.Animated>
      </View>
     );
  }
}
```

I am calling up all the earthquakes in the past 30 days. 
So I thought I'd just place down `region={this.state.marker}` to get it zoomed into the last marker, but that doesn't work. It just places me above Africa, where no markers are set. Does anyone know what could work?

Edit:

My constructor / componentWillMount:

```
class Additional extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      region: {
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      },
      markers: [],
      loaded: false
    }

  }

componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (posData) => {
        this.setState({
          region: {
            latitude: posData.coords.latitude,
            longitude: posData.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            accuracy: posData.coords.accuracy
          }
        });
      },
      (error) => alert(error.message),
      {timeout: 10000}
    );
    this.getEarthquakes()
  }
```

UPDATE 18-01-2018:

After not having worked on it for almost a month I found the piece of code that is throwing sadness into the mix.

UPDATE 18-01-2018:

I thought I found the piece of code that threw sadness into the mix. But it now works after repasting the code. Very confusing. It might just be Lihini's keen eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `this.state.marker` anywhere for it to work. Try setting the state first.

```
getEarthquakes(){       
    return fetch('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData =>{
       var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < responseData.features.length; i++) {
          var coords = responseData.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          var marker = {
            key: responseData.features[i].id,
            coordinate: {
              latitude: coords[1],
              longitude: coords[0],
            }
          }
          markers.push(marker);
        }

        this.setState({
          markers: markers,
          loaded: true,
          marker: markers[markers.length-1]   // set marker state
        });
      }
    ).done();   
}
```

EDIT

Notice this code piece. You're using `this.state.marker` as the region.

```
<MapView.Animated
      style={styles.map}
      region={this.state.marker}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      followUserLocation={true}>

         {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
            <MapView.Marker
              key={marker.key}
              coordinate={marker.coordinate}
            />
         ))}
</MapView.Animated>
```

And now notice what you're storing as the state in the below code piece.

```
this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: posData.coords.latitude,
        longitude: posData.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        accuracy: posData.coords.accuracy
      }
});
```

You're setting `this.state.region` whereas you should be setting `this.state.marker` based on your above code. Hence try changing above to

```
this.setState({
      marker: {
        latitude: posData.coords.latitude,
        longitude: posData.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        accuracy: posData.coords.accuracy
      }
});
```

Comment: My bad. I changed the code.
`this.setState({
          markers: markers,
          loaded: true,
          marker: markers[markers.length-1]   // set marker state
        });`

I tried pushing a new state for lat and long but the region it goes to is the one I have set as default, still. Should it work like this, or am I missing something?

Comment: Change the marker state also, since it points to the last marker added previously.

Comment: I tried spitting around but it doesn't want to update after the my original region set. I've updated the original code with the `state` code. Could you please quickly look it over when you have the time to see if anything looks off? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for disappearing. I had to do other work before continuining with my code. 

I found the 'bug', after renaming everything it still didn't work, then I deleted the a piece of code I didn't add here, sorry for that. `I updated the post to show what is wrong with the code. The code I took out is code I need, so that's too bad.